# How is my function not inheriting from global variable[python]?

Tags: python, error-handling, pygame, global, local

in the global frame, I set timetest = True, but when i run this function is says that timetest was referenced before assignment.

```
def hover(leftmost,rightmost,downmost,upmost,characterpicked):
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
    if event.pos[0] > leftmost and event.pos[0] < rightmost:
        if event.pos[1] > downmost and event.pos[1] < upmost:
                #not complete
            if timetest == True:
                    #original time touched name
                timetestorg = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                timetest = False
                print(timetestorg)
            print(pygame.time.get_ticks())
                #checks a few seconds after
            if (pygame.time.get_ticks() > timetestorg + 700 and pygame.time.get_ticks() < timetestorg + 800):
                    #check location still good
                if event.pos[0] > leftmost and event.pos[0] < rightmost:
                    if event.pos[1] > downmost and event.pos[1] < upmost:
                    #create person object called ness
                        name = "player" + str(playernum)
                        playernum += 1
                        name = Person(characterpicked)
                    #put selected on screen
                        creation = True
                        chosen = myfont.render("Selected", 1, (0,0,0))
                            #make sure to check if you changed choseness to chosen
                        timetest = True
```

line 39, in hover
    if timetest == True:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'timetest' referenced before assignment

Comment: `global timetest` in your function